# Creating new columns from data in other columns based on primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

- 7.1 List the employee name, employee title, manager name, and manager title for each employee.
- Use clear column aliases for your results, and do not exclude any employees in your list.

I'm new to SQL so bear with me. I've managed to have the output list of every employee, their job title, and the employee ID of the employee of they report to (aka their manager). I can't for the life of me figure out how to properly add two additional columns (`ManagerName` and `ManagerJobTitle`) with the necessary correct information in it.

Here is my query so far.

```
Select (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as EmployeeName, Title as JobTitle, ReportsTo
From Employees E
Order By ReportsTo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show any schema for your tables, but from your query I can see you are missing the join with the manager table, from where those two columns where probably supposed to come.

**Edit:** OK, now I get it. The employee table relates to itself. You didn't specified the PK for the table, so I'll assume the Employee has an Id. If the key is another column, just change it in the query below:

```
Select (E FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName) as EmployeeName, 
      E.Title as JobTitle,           
      (R.FirstName + ' ' + R.LastName) as 'ManagerName', 
      R.Title as 'ManagerTitle'
From Employees E
  LEFT JOIN 
     Employees R ON E.ReportsTo = R.Id
Order By ReportsTo
```

**Edit 2:** Changed from `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`, as a employee can have no manager.

Comment: There is no manager table. The manager's ID and information is all listed within the same Employees table as everyone else. How would I include the Schema for this?

Comment: Thank you. I had figured out the answer before I read this but this is exactly correct.

Comment: @GabrielRainha .. Nice copy and paste .. How could you just copy my query and paste it as your answer? I am marking this for **moderator** review.

Comment: @Indra just check the edit history. You'll see I just adjusted the answer to make it better. And yes, your answer is just as right as mine. But suit yourself if you'd like a review.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select (E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName) as EmployeeName, E.Title as JobTitle, mgr.ReportsTo, (mgr.FirstName + ' ' + mgr.LastName) as ManagerName, mgr.Title as MamagerJobTitle
From Employees E
Left join Employees mgr on E.EmployeeID = mgr.ReportsTo
Order By ReportsTo
```

Note: As per my understanding, ReportsTo column has employeeID who have report to any manger, if not please replace that column with mgr.ReportsTo